# having null pointer exception(not always) when started using action bar sherlock library

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, actionbarsherlock

So i am using action bar sherlock library for the action bar in my app.Even though i am not sure the problem occur because of that , but i feel like its due to abs? but the weird thing, when i restart the phone and ADT and delete the app then clean the project and run the project it works again.But then while its working fine,then it might suddenly stop working again. I need to fix this problem.Thank million!

> 10-12 23:40:51.905: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.onHoverEvent,
>   referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.onHoverEvent
>   10-12 23:40:51.905: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 4266:
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.onHoverEvent
>   (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z 10-12 23:40:51.905: D/dalvikvm(1528):
>   VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 10-12 23:40:51.905:
>   D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;.onHoverEvent
>   (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z 10-12 23:40:51.915: I/dalvikvm(1528):
>   Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.getAlpha, referenced
>   from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getAlpha
>   10-12 23:40:51.915: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 3019: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F 10-12
>   23:40:51.915: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
>   10-12 23:40:51.915: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getAlpha
>   ()F 10-12 23:40:51.915: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.getTranslationY, referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getTranslationY
>   10-12 23:40:51.915: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 3020: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F 10-12
>   23:40:51.915: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
>   10-12 23:40:51.915: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getTranslationY
>   ()F 10-12 23:40:51.915: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.setAlpha, referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.setAlpha
>   10-12 23:40:51.915: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 3023: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V 10-12
>   23:40:51.915: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
>   10-12 23:40:51.915: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setAlpha
>   (F)V 10-12 23:40:51.915: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.setTranslationY, referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.setTranslationY
>   10-12 23:40:51.915: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 3030: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V 10-12
>   23:40:51.915: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
>   10-12 23:40:51.915: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setTranslationY
>   (F)V 10-12 23:40:51.925: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from
>   method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView. 10-12
>   23:40:51.925: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   300: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo
>   (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   10-12 23:40:51.925: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x01d1 10-12 23:40:51.925: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView. 10-12
>   23:40:51.925: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   296: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo
>   (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   10-12 23:40:51.925: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x01df 10-12 23:40:51.925: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code
>   0x01d4-01d8 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.
>   (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V 10-12
>   23:40:51.925: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x01e2-01e8 in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.
>   (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V 10-12
>   23:40:51.955: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.view.ViewGroup.getAlpha, referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getAlpha
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 2789: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F 10-12 23:40:51.955:
>   D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b 10-12
>   23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getAlpha
>   ()F 10-12 23:40:51.955: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.view.ViewGroup.getTranslationX, referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getTranslationX
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 2794: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F 10-12
>   23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationX
>   ()F 10-12 23:40:51.955: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.view.ViewGroup.getTranslationY, referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getTranslationY
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 2795: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F 10-12
>   23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationY
>   ()F 10-12 23:40:51.955: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.view.ViewGroup.setAlpha, referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setAlpha
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 2810: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V 10-12
>   23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setAlpha
>   (F)V 10-12 23:40:51.955: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.view.ViewGroup.setTranslationX, referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setTranslationX
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 2814: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V 10-12
>   23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationX
>   (F)V 10-12 23:40:51.955: I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   android.view.ViewGroup.setTranslationY, referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setTranslationY
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 2815: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V 10-12
>   23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
>   10-12 23:40:51.955: D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationY
>   (F)V 10-12 23:40:51.985: D/dalvikvm(1528): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed
>   1437 objects / 98064 bytes in 28ms 10-12 23:40:52.285:
>   I/dalvikvm(1528): Could not find method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onHoverEvent,
>   referenced from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.dispatchHoverEvent
>   10-12 23:40:52.285: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 5127:
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.onHoverEvent
>   (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z 10-12 23:40:52.285: D/dalvikvm(1528):
>   VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000 10-12 23:40:52.285:
>   D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in
>   Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.dispatchHoverEvent
>   (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z 10-12 23:40:52.285: I/dalvikvm(1528):
>   Could not find method
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent, referenced
>   from method
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent
>   10-12 23:40:52.285: W/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 3022: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent
>   (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V 10-12 23:40:52.285:
>   D/dalvikvm(1528): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006 10-12
>   23:40:52.345: D/AndroidRuntime(1528): Shutting down VM 10-12
>   23:40:52.345: W/dalvikvm(1528): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8) 10-12 23:40:52.355:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-12 23:40:52.355:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.id11313982.freejokesapp/com.id11313982.freejokesapp.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 10-12 23:40:52.355:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
>   10-12 23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
>   10-12 23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135) 10-12
>   23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
>   10-12 23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-12
>   23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 10-12 23:40:52.355:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937) 10-12
>   23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-12
>   23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 10-12 23:40:52.355:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   10-12 23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 10-12
>   23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-12 23:40:52.355:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1528): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-12 23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   com.id11313982.freejokesapp.activities.MainActivity.networkStatusMessage(MainActivity.java:202)
>   10-12 23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   com.id11313982.freejokesapp.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78) 10-12 23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
>   10-12 23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
>   10-12 23:40:52.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1528): ... 11 more

```
public void networkStatusMessage()  
{
    mJokeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joke_portion_textview_main_activity);
        HelperClass.ShowErrorMessage(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.connection_not_available_status_localjokeread));
        mJokeView.setText(getString(R.string.connection_not_available_status_localjokeread));
        mJokeView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    mJokeTitleView.setText("");
            }

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        helperClass = new HelperClass();
    stillRandomJoke = true;
        if(helperClass.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this))
    {
        dataBundle = new Bundle();
        dataBundle = helperClass.restoreCategoryPreference(MainActivity.this);
            if(dataBundle.getString(CATEGORY_NAME) != null && dataBundle.getInt(CATEGORY_ID) != 0)
        {
            startJokeId = dataBundle.getInt(FROM_ID);
                endJokeId = dataBundle.getInt(TO_ID);
                currentJokeId = helperClass.restoreJokeIDPreference(MainActivity.this);

                stillRandomJoke = false;
                IssueHTTPRequestForEachJoke(SELECTED_JOKE_URL + currentJokeId);
        }
        else
                IssueHTTPRequestForEachJoke(RANDOM_JOKE_URL);
    }
    else
        networkStatusMessage();
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code (`MainActivity.onCreate()` around line 78 and `MainActivity.networkStatusMessage()` around line 202).

Comment: i think it shd do now. post the code above. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that line 202 of `networkStatusMessage` is this line:

```
mJokeTitleView.setText("");
```

and that `mJokeTitleView` is `null` because you have never set it.

Comment: when i remove that, it dosen't have error anymore. thank you. :) but it is confusing because i am not setting the mJokeTitleView to null but just the white space character?

Comment: @ZawnHtut - I assume from the name that `mJokeTitleView` is a field of your activity class. If you don't set it to anything (by calling `findViewById()`), it has the default value of `null`. That will raise a NPE when you call `setText()`.